# Android RxJava2 API error handling

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am new to `RxJava`.

We are using `Retrofit2 + RxJava2` for calling APIs.

I have the following scenario -

**1. Call Cart API

2. If Cart API fails I need to call Login API

3. On Success of Login API I need to call Cart API again**

> Call {API} -> {API} fails -> call Login API -> on success of Login
>   API -> call {API}.

Like this way, if any API fails I need to call Login API and then call the failed API.

Whats the best way handle this.

Comment: Sounds like you want to refresh a login token/session. If that's the case maybe it's worth looking into the OkHttp authenticator api or if you can't use it, then maybe use interceptors.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
api.processCart()
    .retryWhen(errors -> errors
                           .filter(it -> it == LOGIN_ERROR)
                           .flatMap(api.login())
```

Beware that this could create a never-ending loop if you are not careful. You can insert any logic you want in the `retryWhen` handler. As in the example, you could check the type of the error and decide if you need to relogin or do something else.

But if you need to do this for every api call, it'd be worth taking a look at Fred's comment.